# how do I merge multiple xlsx sheets in r

Tags: r

run the code below in attempt to merge 3 sheets

```
Data_v01 <- merge(
              Data, 
              crop_income_cal,
              livestock_income_cal, 
              by = "parent_index_new", 
              all.x = TRUE, 
              all.y = TRUE)
```

but got an error

Error in fix.by(by.x, x) :
'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical

Comment: You have to merge 2 things at a time. So first merge two, and then merge the third on the result of the former merge

Comment: And how exactly do you suppose this can be answered? There is nothing to work with, so your error cannot be reproduced. Please read some topics (or the FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r?tab=Frequent) on how to create proper sample data, so people here can actually see what you are working with, and can provide adequate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tidyverse and readxl libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
```

#See your excel sheets

```
excel_sheets("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx")
#Combine all your sheets 
excel_sheets("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx") %>% map_df(~read_xlsx("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx",.))
```

you can also use

```
excel_sheets("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx") %>% map(~read_xlsx("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx",.))

#Put the result in a object 

excel_sheets("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx") %>% map(~read_xlsx("path/to/your/file/file.xlsx",.)) -> my_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce` to merge a list of multiple data.frames

```
Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("parent_index_new"), all = T), list(Data, crop_income_cal, livestock_income_cal))
```